# Jquery Datatables adding extra column

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, datatables

I am facing a strange issue in the jquery datatables. It adds a extra empty column only in IE8. json result looks good. It works well in all other browsers. I am not sure why it adds extra column.

screen shot attached below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz2mf.jpg

Comment: Here is an example. I cannot replicate in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Gopal_Tiwari/UCzkY/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in the way we were forming our jQuery header. We found some unwanted comma's in it. We removed them and then it started working.